# How to pass additional data to lightning-button-menu onselect handler?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-buttonmenu

Is there any way to pass additional data to a button-menu `onselect` hander?

I have a lightning-button-menu in a loop (this is a minimal example, and not a real-world case). When a menu item is selected, then `handleActionsMenuSelect` is called with a single `event` argument. The `event.detail.value` is set to the `value` of the menu item selected, in this case either `edit` or `delete`.

But since the menu is in a loop, I also need to determine which `item` to edit or delete. I tried putting `item.id` in the menu's `value`, but that does not appear in the `event` data.

Is there any way i can also pass the associated `item.id` to `handleActionsMenuSelect`?

```
            <template for:each={items} for:item="item">
              <lightning-button-menu label="Actions" value={item.id} onselect={handleActionsMenuSelect}>
                <lightning-menu-item label="Edit" value="edit"></lightning-menu-item>
                <lightning-menu-item label="Delete" value="delete"></lightning-menu-item>
              </lightning-button-menu>
            </template>
```

Comment: Add data-id and set your id as required and in handler you can get event.target.dataset.id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could leverage `data-*` attribute: define an HTML attribute whose name must start with `data-` and can contain only letters, numbers, dashes, periods, colons, and underscores, i.e. `data-id={item.id}`.
In Javascript `event.currentTarget.dataset` will hold every property defined in HTML, in order to get the name of the property just remove the `data-` prefix and remove the dashes keeping in mind that you have to capitalize the next letter every time you remove a dash. I.E. The HTML attribute `data-very-long-name="something"` will become `dataset.veryLongName`.
So you'll find the id in `event.currentTarget.dataset.id`.

```html
<template for:each={items} for:item="item">
  <lightning-button-menu label="Actions" data-id={item.id} onselect={handleActionsMenuSelect}>
    <lightning-menu-item label="Edit" value="edit"></lightning-menu-item>
    <lightning-menu-item label="Delete" value="delete"></lightning-menu-item>
  </lightning-button-menu>
</template>
```

```js
handleActionsMenuSelect(event) {
    const recordId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
    console.log('recordId:', recordId);
}
```

Comment: I didnt think to add it as answer and rather added same as comment :D

Comment: Thank you @RubenDG.